# Why is my Everstone broken?

Tags: magikarp-jump

I was comparing items with a friend of mine and he had an unbroken Everstone (the name was in french I don't remember what it was) and mine was broken. The tooltip on his said that it would prevent his Pokémon from evolving.

Does that mean that since mine is broken I'll get a Gyarados at some point? And why would mine be broken?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you tap your magikarp enough times in a row, the everstone it holds will break.

This causes your magikarp to evolve once it levels up and its level is > 20.

It is a one time event.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning as well that the everstone "regenerates" with each new Magikarp.

Comment: Bonus: If you have a golden magikarp, you can deliberately break the everstone and get a red gyarados. You can also get a red gyarados with other events but it is always based on chance.